# Is the Coefficient of Variation valid for data which does not follow a normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics, coefficient-of-variation, dispersion

I am trying to compare the dispersion of several data vectors. As an example I have that via two methods produces one vector of data that fits a normal distribution and other one that follows an exponential distr. Is it valid to compare the CV of both and according to that affirm that one is more disperse than other? Should I somehow consider that both set of points do not fit the same pdf?

Comment: It's a relationship of the standard deviation to the mean. It is meaningless for distributions with 0 mean. That includes some normal distributions. I think it is actually more meaningful for distributions concentrated on the positive portion of the real line like the exponential distribution. I don't think it has an interpretation when  the mean is negative and certainly not for distributions that don't have a finite mean such as a Cauchy distribution.

Comment: @Wladimir I would usually not be inclined to use CV on data that *did* follow a single normal distribution. It is primarily useful when variance is proportional to the square of the mean, which practically speaking is typically restricted to strictly positive random variables.

Comment: @Glen_b my two data vectors follow a normal and exponential distribution each. And for both there are only positive values. What would you recommend in case of an exponential distribution to measure dispersion?

Comment: How can you know your data are drawn from these distributions?

Comment: @Glen_b following the kolmogorov smirnov test, after computing the p-value of several distributions (normal, expon, pareto, etc.), I can confirm that the data follows the distribution with the highest p-value. I confirmed this also by drawing the histogram and the corresponding fitted pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments, but first, very short: CV is mostly useful on distributions concentrated on the positive numbers, excluding normal distributions!

> It's a relationship of the standard deviation to the mean. It is
>   meaningless for distributions with 0 mean. That includes some normal
>   distributions. I think it is actually more meaningful for
>   distributions concentrated on the positive portion of the real line
>   like the exponential distribution. I don't think it has an
>   interpretation when the mean is negative and certainly not for
>   distributions that don't have a finite mean such as a Cauchy
>   distribution.

– Michael R. Chernick

> @Wladimir I would usually not be inclined to use CV on data that did
>   follow a single normal distribution. It is primarily useful when
>   variance is proportional to the square of the mean, which practically
>   speaking is typically restricted to strictly positive random
>   variables.

– Glen_b -Reinstate Monica